# Stripe response if popup is cancelled

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I use the following code to receive payment with Stripe. When the user click a .stripe-button the user redirects to a popup to perform the payment. Then I show a loading overlay so the user does not go do anything on the payment page. When the Stripe token is created the popup closes and the page post the form.

But how can I get a response when the popup is cancelled or simply closed, and show a message on the page e.g. "You cancelled the payment, please try again".

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment">

                <input type="submit" id="stripe" class="full-button" data-loader="true" value="Pay with VISA" />
                <input type="submit" id="stripe" class="full-button" data-loader="true" value="Pay with Mastercard" />
                <input type="submit" id="stripe" class="full-button" data-loader="true" value="Pay with Other Card" />

            </form>

            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
            <script>
              var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                key: 'test',
                image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
                token: function(token) {
                    $("#payment").append('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" value="'+token.id+'" />');
                    // and re-submit
                    $("#payment").submit();
                }
              });

              $('#stripe').on('click', function(e) {
                // Open Checkout with further options
                handler.open({
                  name: 'Test',
                  description: 'Pay for order',
                  amount: 2000,
                  email: 'test@gmail.com',
                  image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png'
                });
                e.preventDefault();
              });

              // Close Checkout on page navigation
              $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                handler.close();
              });

//show loader after click
    if($("[data-loader=true]").length){

        $("[data-loader=true]").click(function() {

            $("#loader").show();

        });

    }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `closed:` option for the `open` function

```
handler.open({
 name: 'Test',
 description: 'Pay for order',
 amount: 2000,
 email: 'test@gmail.com',
 image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
 //ADD THIS LINE HERE:
 closed: function() {{ ChargeCancelled();}} });
```